# Embedding actix-web into a struct so that I can start/stop server

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I'm working on embedding actix-web into a binding library. I would like to declare a `HttpServer` within a struct so that I can easily call `.start()` and `.system_exit()`. From my very basic reading of [the source code](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/3431fff4d7f2c39576f8c6070df09f169abf12a8/src/server/http.rs#L57-L445) it's already implemented as a struct with two dependencies: `<H, F>`. It also comes with a factory to instantiate itself.

If I'm understanding this correctly, then I would have to implement the `HttpServer` as a dependency in my new struct and add my own characteristics within it. My previous thought was to create a new struct and just declare `HttpServer` as a property within it. That seemed troublesome with the generics that needed to be declared within it.

What I've come up with so far is:

```
struct CustomServer<T> {
    srv: T,
}

impl<T> CustomServer<T>
where
    T: HttpServer,
{
    fn init() {
        self.srv = HttpServer::new(|| App /* etc. */)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm grasping at straws or in the right direction.

The question is: how should/can I go about defining a struct that has HttpServer and it's functions accessible in my struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpServer` is a [generic struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html#in-struct-definitions), not a [trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html) (so “`T: HttpServer`” doesn’t make sense).

You can either make a generic struct that contains a totally arbitrary instantiation of `HttpServer` (this is likely not very useful to you):

```
struct CustomServer<H: IntoHttpHandler + 'static, F: Fn() -> H + Send + Clone + 'static> {
    srv: HttpServer<H, F>,
}

impl<H: IntoHttpHandler + 'static, F: Fn() -> H + Send + Clone + 'static> CustomServer<H, F> {
    fn new(factory: F) -> CustomServer<H, F> {
        CustomServer {
            srv: HttpServer::new(factory),
        }
    }
}
```

or a concrete struct that contains a particular kind of `HttpServer` (I’m guessing this is what you’ll want, though it’s hard to say without details of your use case):

```
struct CustomServer {
    srv: HttpServer<App, fn() -> App>,
}

impl CustomServer {
    fn new() -> CustomServer {
        CustomServer {
            srv: HttpServer::new(|| App),
        }
    }
}
```

There are also many points in between (e.g. specialize `H` but not `F`, or specialize slightly based on other generic parameters), depending on what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Ahhhhh. I ended up going with the generic struct in case I want to have more flexibility. Thank you very much, I was definitely overthinking this. :-(

Comment: Hmmm strange...when I attempt initializing the struct I'm getting: server expected fn pointer, found closure: let server = server::new(
        || App::new()
          .middleware(middleware::Logger::default())
          .default_resource(|r| r.f(index))
      );
      Ok(CustomServer {
        address: address.value(),
        port: port.value() as i32,
        server: server
      }). Why would it complain about the closure, it's following the same structure.

Comment: Sorry the above includes the error, then exactly what I'm feeding into the struct.

Comment: @ddibiase The difference between a function and a closure is that a closure brings in variables from the surrounding scope: in this case, `index`. This would be a case where you need to make the struct generic in `F` and use impl trait to represent the closure in the return type (`fn new() -> CustomServer<impl Fn() -> App>`).

Comment: I see. I forget that closures bring in scope like that. I decided to go with the concrete struct so now I'm thinking through what you mentioned. Sorry just really confused and grasping at comprehending a few things happening here. :-p

Comment: sorry I'm still stumped by this. I've posted a pastebin with some pseudo code that roughly describes what I'm doing: https://pastebin.com/aUreUhH6  I'm still getting "expected fn pointer, found closure" and I feel like I'm just not grasping this entirely.